# GIT and Development URL's point to production

Tags: git, github

I am experimenting with GIT for version control. I have a production environment that I created a repo for [HERE](https://github.com/marklocklear/wp_blog), then did a git clone locally. I created/modified the wp-config to work with my local DB. The index page loads, but all of the links for any pages or post point to the production URLs.

How can I make this so running the local instance allows me to browse to all the local pages/posts?

Comment: Do you have _.htaccess_ file in the folder that also contains _wp-config.php_?

Comment: No, there is not .htaccess file locally. Should there be?

Comment: If you locally use WAMP or MAMP that both use Apache as a server you should have the _.htaccess_ file. Try deleting  the local _wp-config.php_ file, open WordPress URL in the browser and follow the installation process. The _.htaccess_ file will be crated automatically.

Comment: Good call, I did this, and while my DB is out of sync, at least I can browse around the site. I am going to look into a db sync solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [WP DB Migrate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to export the DB in the production environment. It allows you to rewrite URLs. Then you import that in your local DB.

Answer (score 3):

Besides doing the find and replace on the domain as saved in the site's database, you'll also want to either:

- ignore and remove the wp-config.php file from your git repo (so that the local development instance database connection info doesn't keep overwriting the server's and vice versa), or
- add some environment specific configuration (can be a conditional statement in the wp-config, but better yet- should be a call to check for the existence of and use an external database config file whose name matches the environment)

Answer (score 2):

My preferred method is to use WP CLI's [`search-replace`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) command to swap out domains in my local site. If I have `example.com` on my live site, I'll use `example.local` on my local install, so the command to fix URLs on the dev site would be:

```
wp search-replace example.com example.local
```